# Save the Deep learning model by R language

Tags: r, model, save, h2o

I have established a deep learning model with the h2o package of the R software. I gained a model with good presence and I wanna to save it. However, I tried all kinds of methods but failed. The code "save()" and "save.image()" are provided in the base package of R software. I used the "save()" function to conserve my model. But when I want to use the built model to run new data, it is said that the "model" object is not found in the function. I am really confused about this problem for a few days. If you have any good ideas, just tell me. Thanks for your reading~

```
load("F:/R/Rstudy/myfile") ##download the saved file
library(h2o)
h2o.init()
Te <- read.csv("F:/Rdata/Test.csv") ##  import testing data
Te <- as.h2o(Te)
Te[,2] <- as.factor(Te[,2])
perf <- h2o.performance(model, Te) ## test model
```

> ERROR: Unexpected HTTP Status code: 404 Not Found (url = http://localhost:54321/3/ModelMetrics/models/DeepLearning_model_R_1533035975237_1/frames/RTMP_sid_8185_2)
>
> ERROR MESSAGE:
>    Object 'DeepLearning_model_R_1533035975237_1' not found in function: predict for  argument: model

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below to save and retrieve the model.

## build the model

model <- h2o.deeplearning(params)

## save the model

model_path <- h2o.saveModel(object=model, path=getwd(), force=TRUE)

print(model_path)
/tmp/mymodel/DeepLearning_model_R_1441838096933

## load the model

saved_model <- h2o.loadModel(model_path)

Reference - http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/save-and-load-model.html

Hope this helps,
ND

Comment: Thank you for your method! I used a similar method before. The saved model can only be used when the R software is opening. If I close the R software and open it again, the saved model can't be used.

Comment: That is true, as the model is no more available in the environment.